# Calculate avg time in mysql from last 7 days

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

> **Tablename**=run_detail
>
> > I have to calculate avg time of jobs for last 7 days, but in somecases
> > number of runs could be less than 7 days. eg abc has only 2 run_date.
> > **(4.5+6+.....+7)/7=5.83** and **(23.9+45.7)/2=34.8** and also need to
> > calculate based on latest 7 runs. for eg. **2020-07-04 to 2020-07-10**,
> > not from **2020-07-01**

```
Job_name run_date   rownum count  elapsed_time(sec) avg_time
xyz      2020-07-01   1     10       4.5             ?
xyz      2020-07-02   2     10       6               ?
.......  
xyz      2020-07-10   10    10       7.0             ?
abc      2020-07-01   1      2       23.9            ?
abc      2020-07-02   2      2       45.7            ?
```

> **Desired Output**

```
Job_name run_date   rownum count  elapsed_time(sec) avg_time
xyz      2020-07-01   1     10       4.5             5.83
xyz      2020-07-02   2     10       6               5.83
.......  
xyz      2020-07-10   10    10       7.0             5.83
abc      2020-07-01   1      2       23.9            34.8
abc      2020-07-02   2      2       45.7            34.8
```

> Could you please help how to achieve the avg time in mysql

Comment: I am removing the Teradata tags because the question is explicitly about MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the overage over the preceding 7 days, you can use a window functions:

```
select t.*,
       avg(elapsed_time) over (partition by job_name
                               order by run_date
                               range between interval -6 day preceding and current row
                              ) as avg_time
from t;
```

Note:  This assumes that you really want six preceding days plus the current date.  If you really want 7 days before to 1 day before (the preceding week), then use:

```
range between interval -7 day preceding and interval -1 day preceding
```

EDIT:

In older versions of MySQL, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select avg(t2.elapsed_time)
        from t t2
        where t2.job_name = t.job_name and
              t2.run_date <= t.run_date and
              t2.run_date > t.run_date - interval 7 day
       ) as avg_time
from t;
```

Adjust the date comparison to get exactly the period you want.

Comment: Gorgon, Can we do it without Windows Function?

Comment: @Ashu . . . Yes.  With much, much worse performance if your data is not small.

Comment: Data is quite small. Can you please how to achieve how to achieve it because I have mysql aurora 5.6